# Will runnable jar file run at host after connection lost ? if yes, how to run?

Tags: linux, unix, jar, host

I have lost connection when I am running a jar file and the process is terminated. How can I overcome situation like this in future?

Comment: see *How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?* http://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a jar and detach the process from the terminal you can do something like this:

```
nohup java -jar application.jar &
```